# Selecting several objects based on array of IDs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity

I have an array of ProgramIDs and would like to create a number of Select statements dynamically depending on how many ProgramIds there are.

For example:

```
  var surveyProgramVar = surveyProgramRepository.Find().Where(x => x.ProgramId == resultsviewmodel.ProgramIds.FirstOrDefault());
```

This is an example of the select statement working with a single ProgramId.FirstOrDefault().  How do I create a list/array of SurveyProgramVars and select for each ProgramIds in the array?

Answer (score 0):

It won't be necessarily optimal, but you might try:

```
var surveyProgramVar = surveyProgramRepository.Find()
                       .Where(x => resultsviewmodel.ProgramIds.Contains(x.ProgramId));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
var surveyProgramVar = surveyProgramRepository.Find().Where(x => resultsviewmodel.ProgramIds.Contains(x.ProgramId));
```

*Tip:* If the `Find()` method does a hit on a database, would be nice if you create a specific method to to a `IN` statment on the query. If you does not do this, it will take all records on a table and filter it in memory (linq to objects), which works but not very nice. Your code could be something like:

```
var surveyProgramVar = surveyProgramRepository.FindByProgramsId(resultsviewmodel.ProgramIds);
```